# Peek at first object of stream with highland.js

Tags: javascript, stream, reactive-programming, highland.js

I want to convert a stream of arbitrary but similarly keyed objects into a stream of CSV-strings. In order to do this, I want to peek at the first object in the stream and make a header-line of the object keys that will be prepended to the stream. I've gotten as far as this:

```es2015
// Convert an object to a DSV
// NOTE: Assumes that all objects have the same properties!
export let toDSV = (delimiter=', ') => stream => {
  let headerStream = stream.fork().head().flatMap(x => _.keys(x).collect());

  return headerStream
    .flatMap(headers => {
      return _.sequence([
        _([headers.join(delimiter)]),
        stream.fork()
          .pick(headers)
          .map(_.values)
          .flatMap(_.collect)
          .invoke('join', [delimiter])
      ]);
    });
};
```

For the following stream

```
_([{
  foo: 1
  bar: 2
  baz: 3
}, {
  foo: 2
  bar: 1
  baz: 4
}])
```

The resulting stream should be :

```
foo, bar, baz
1, 2, 3
2, 1, 4
```

Only the header-row is created though because of what I believe to be a back-pressure problem with `fork()` where the first stream isn't fully consumed.

**So, how can I "peek" at the first element of a stream, and then process the stream based on that information?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your problem is that you're calling `.fork()` on `stream` at the outset: `let headerStream = stream.fork()...`.

Now it's almost like you've got `stream(a)` and `stream(b)`, where `return headerStream.flatMap...` is operating on `stream(b)` and `stream.fork().pick(headers)...` is waiting for you to start operating on `stream(b)`.

Just nix both of those `stream.fork()` calls and you should be set.